# Cleaning error text strings inside Categorical Variable Columns

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame (see below - the real dataset is about 10,000 rows, 26 columns) with errors like '?' or '&#-81;' where there should be a string corresponding to a value like a Premise or a Color.

```
columns = ['Numbers','Premises','Colors','Year']
mat = np.array([
    [10, 'Q', 'Grey', 1942],
    [50, '?', '&#81', 2091],
    [10, 'P', 'Blue', 1814],
    [15, '?', '&#73', 1719],
    [20, 'Q', 'Grey', 2025]
])
df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
df.columns = columns

 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   Numbers   5 non-null      object
 1   Premises  5 non-null      object
 2   Colors    5 non-null      object
 3   Year      5 non-null      object
dtypes: object(4)
```

Those error strings are not missing data because they are text and the field is not empty so df.isnull() :

```
df.isnull()
    Numbers Premises Colors Year
0   False   False    False  False
1   False   False    False  False
2   False   False    False  False
3   False   False    False  False
4   False   False    False  False
```

How could I filter or detection in a object column of 10,000 rows for unknown string errors?